Is there any alternative for searching nearby places without using Google map Places API?
I am trying to search nearby places by types ( such as Hospital, Restaurant,..) from my current places, I used gg map API but I realised that I need to pay for this services, can anyone have another suggestion for searching nearby places using another API services. I am using Android studio to make a traveling mobile app
The following is the error i got when i try to fetch data from GG API:
{
"error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [],
"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
Thanks for your supportS <3
I tried to approach Mapbox but idk whether it can support nearby searching

This question is off-topic for SO, but FYI, although it requires billing enabled and is a paid service, Google Cloud comes with a "free" tier in the for of credits they apply to your bill, so you won't actually pay anything unless you have very high usage.
